# Can a hypervisor with paravirtualized guests benefit from virtualization extensions?

Tags: virtualization, hypervisor, paravirtualization

A hypervisor developer claimed that, even though they only support paravirtualized guests, the virtualization would still be faster on a platform with hardware virtualization extensions.

Does this make sense? And through which mechanism could there even be a performance gain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. In a very abstract sense, there are two things a VMM needs to do: allow the guest to do things it needs to, and prevent it from doing things it shouldn't. Paravirtualization solves the first part. Hardware virtualization extensions are very effective at solving the second part.

Comment: I had a look at the ARM manual to find some concrete examples for this. I found the trap controls that can disable certain instructions or stop access to special registers.
Would this be something that is only possible with hardware virtualization extensions or simply more efficient?